# Ecto's fragment Compile Error

Tags: sql, postgresql, elixir, ecto

I'm trying to systematize the act of searching my Postgres JSON columns using Ecto's fragment.

So let's assume I have the following object in the `profile` column

```
{
  "first_name": "Margarita",
  "last_name": "Fernandez",
  "rut": "17.754.041-2"
}
```

and I'm trying to do something like

```
from(u in Users.User, where: fragment("?->>'first_name' LIKE ?", u.profile, ^("%" <> "Marga" <> "%"))) |> Users.Repo.all
```

but in a function

```
def search(field, value) do
    from(u in Users.User, where: fragment("?->>'#{field}' LIKE ?", u.profile, ^("%" <> value <> "%"))) |> Repo.all
end
```

But I get the following error

```
** (Ecto.Query.CompileError) fragment(...) expects the first argument to be a string for SQL fragments, a keyword list, or an interpolated value, got: `"?->>'#{field}' LIKE ?"`
```

I've tried to escape it, interpolated in a previous variable but there's something I'm doing wrong.

Any hints?

Comment: Try `fragment("?->>? LIKE ?", u.profile, ^field, ^("%" <> value <> "%"))`?

Comment: Doing that raises a REALLY weird error `== Compilation error on file web/controllers/exchange_controller.ex ==
** (CompileError) web/controllers/exchange_controller.ex:1: cannot define module Users.ExchangeController because it is currently being defined in web/controllers/exchange_controller.ex:1
    (stdlib) erl_eval.erl:670: :erl_eval.do_apply/6
    (elixir) lib/kernel/parallel_compiler.ex:117: anonymous fn/4 in Kernel.ParallelCompiler.spawn_compilers/1
`

Comment: As far as I can understand, this error makes no sense.

Comment: That error looks unrelated to the change. Can you try restarting the app?

Comment: Restarting the app was sufficient. Turn your comment into an answer so I can accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do string interpolation like that with `fragment`. In this particular case, you can fix this by putting `?` after `->>` and putting `^field` in the `fragment` arguments:

```
fragment("?->>? LIKE ?", u.profile, ^field, ^("%" <> value <> "%"))
```